# Как форматировать строку

Tags: c++, sql, qt

Необходимо форматировать строку в `query` запросе, что бы в неё были включены `переменные`.

```
inline bool insertDate(int id, char name){
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.exec("INSERT INTO public.themes("
               ""ID_theme", name)"
               "VALUES ({id}), ({name})");
    return(true);
}
```

Пробовал использовать `std::format`, но выводилась ошибка, что `format` нет в `std`.

Пытался присвоить строки запроса строковой переменной (`stoi`, `atoi`, `snprintf`), но каждый раз  выводилась ошибка о невозможности выполнить запрос.

Каким способом можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Используйте параметризованные запросы. Документация: [Executing SQL Statements](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-sqlstatements.html). Смотрите `prepare` и `bindValue`.